# Get height and width of the document from just url link to the document

Tags: jquery, vb.net

I am using vb.net and jquery. Here is the problem. Using jquery i load different url links to different documents in iframe. Like this:

```
document.getElementById('iFrame').src = url;
```

Is there anyway that i can get the height and width of the document using this url? 
As when this iFrame is loaded i cannot get the height or width.

Comment: What are you looking to do exactly? If I've got a monitor sitting at full screen with a resolution of 2000px x 2000px, my document dimensions will be 2000px x 2000px, irrelevant of how much content is on the screen :/

Comment: @ChrisKempen: i am trying to load data into iFrame and before i do that i want to know height and width so i can adjust that and dont see any scrollbars.

Comment: As was, uh, pointed out, the problem with doing what you want to do is that it can only ever work on fixed width sites. Flexible width sites, which are becoming more common again, will almost always be the width of your iFrame, whatever the size.  If you know that is the case with the site you want to load, then you will also need to overcome the xss problem in order to access the iFrame.  You'd be better off finding another solution, like using a fixed width around yourself (around 850-900px for desktop is standard at the moment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery you can try this. You can access the iframe elements only if the parent and iframe are in the same domain.

```
$("iframe").load(function(){

    var $body = $(this).contents().find("body")
    var height = $body.height();
    var width = $body.width();

    //Using these values you can adjust the iframe height and widht.

}).attr("src", url);
```

Comment: @ShankarSangoli: This is not working i am getting: Error: Permission denied

Comment: I mentioned in my answer the iframe should be in the same domain to access its elements.

Answer (score -1):

Best solution I've found to change the height of the frame automatically in jQuery:

```
$('#frmForm').load(function() {
    var h = $('#frmForm').contents().find("body").height();
    $('#frmForm').css('height', h + 'px');
});
```

Comment: Please make the complete answer in english

Comment: Please translate your answer to English.